# Run a child program while periodically reading from a file, and knowing when the child ends

Tags: c, linux

I have a series of programs which I would like to run, they all change a file, lets call it example.txt, as they run.

I'm trying to write a program which can run the series of programs, save the amount of time each program takes, and have snapshots of the example.txt file during it's execution. I'm only interested in a single line in example.txt, and already have the code for pulling this out, it is just a matter of calling a function.

In windows I would use the `spawn()` family of functions, but this does not seem to be an option in linux. I also know how to time the program (start_time - end_time).

I need a function which spawns the child concurrently with the parent, and then provides a message when the child has finished so the parent can grab the system time.

Comment: You want to look at `fork` and `wait` system calls.

Comment: Take a look at  `fork`  http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After breaking the problem down it became much easier.

Problem 1: How to spawn a child?

Problem 2: How to get the parent to end after getting a 'notification' from the child ending.

To solve problem 1 meant just reading the documentation for `fork()`

```
 switch ((pid = fork())) {
            case -1:
                    /* fork() has failed */
                    perror("fork");
                    break;
            case 0:
                    /* Processed by the child */
                    execv("child", my_args);
                    puts("execv() has failed");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    break;
            default:
                    /* processed by the parent  */
                    puts("Message from the parent");
                    break;
    }
```

Problem 2 was solved by building on this with a `wait()` call, `waitpid()` to be precise. The following code was just added to the bottom of the code above.

```
    int status;
    while(!waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG)) {
            /* Parent does stuff while waiting for child */
    }
    /* Parent gets here once child has ended */
```

With the above comments it is clear where to add this into my code. I added the comments to make it more of a general solution.

Inside the while loop I read from the file, and after breaking from the while loop I will grab the end system time.